# FFMPEG Encode with MacBook Pro AMD GPU

Tags: ffmpeg

When I encode h264 video on my Macbook Pro with ffmpeg it uses the intel CPU and not the dedicated AMD Radeon Pro 560 GPU.

I am assuming the dedicated GPU would be faster at encoding h264 video. Is it possible for ffmpeg to use the GPU to encode instead of the CPU.

I installed ffmpeg via homebrew.

Comment: Possible. Get a dated binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_amf` to see options.

Comment: Probably not faster. Hardware h264 doesn’t use the standard GPU vector units. It uses fixed function accelerators that are integrated into the GPU.